# Grabbing Info From Another App

Tags: java, android, mobile

I'm looking for information on how/if you can grab information from another app in Android. For example, if I wanted to make an app that checked which song was being played in the Music app at the moment. Is this even possible? I Googled around and searched on here but didn't find much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can communicate with other apps via [intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html).  What communication is possible depends on what that particular actions that app made available.

Comment: That helped my search a bit. I found this, which may be what I was looking for:

http://www.alexc.me/android-music-app-service-currently-playing-song/231/

Comment: Keep in mind that you should never use undocumented interfaces.  These are likely to change over time, and will cause you nothing but problems.  You app will break randomly, or only on certain phones, etc.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this even possible?

Only if the app exposes an API for you to use, one that is documented and supported by the application's developer.